# Returning total rows for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have query below that returns performance data for a specified SQL instance. The issue I am having is same textdata are returned for different time frames. I am looking for a way to sum up the same rows of textdata and return total cpu, duration, read, write.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
SELECT TOP 40 HostName, DatabaseName, ApplicationName,
       LoginName, CPU, TextData,
       Reads, Writes, Duration, StartTime, EndTime
FROM dbo.PerformanceTable 
WHERE  Duration > 10000
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added a sample screenshot of the results I am getting. Hopefully, that helps. I am looking to get one row for each textdata and a sum of CPU, writes reads, and duration for that one textdata row. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data it's difficult to suggest a solution. If I understood you correctly you want total cpu, duration, read, write for each HostName, DatabaseName, ApplicationName, TextData regardless of their starttime or endtime.

```
SELECT HostName, DatabaseName, ApplicationName,TextData,
       sum(CPU), sum(Reads), sum(Writes), sum(Duration)
FROM dbo.PerformanceTable 
group by HostName, DatabaseName, ApplicationName,TextData
WHERE  Duration > 10000
order by HostName, DatabaseName, ApplicationName,TextData
```

Based on your added screenshot I have revised my answer:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, TextData,
       sum(CPU) total_CPU , sum(Reads) total_Reads, sum(Writes) total_Writes , sum(Duration) total_Duration
FROM dbo.PerformanceTable 
group by DatabaseName, TextData
WHERE  Duration > 10000
order by DatabaseName, TextData
```

Comment: Thanks for much for this. It almost gets me what I am looking for. I am still getting several rows of the same textdata. Wanting to get a sum of runtime for each textdata

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the results I am getting. One row for each distinct textdata and sum reads, writes, CPU, and duration is what I am looking to achieve. Tanks again

Comment: @danKalio thanks for the screen shot. I have  revised my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: You are most welcome @danKalio. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
SELECT TextData,
       SUM(Reads), SUM(Writes), SUM(Duration)
FROM dbo.PerformanceTable 
WHERE Duration > 10000
GROUP BY TextData;
```

Comment: Thanks for much for this. It almost gets me what I am looking for. I am still getting several rows of the same textdata. Wanting to get a sum of runtime for each textdata

Comment: @danKalio . . . That is not possible, due to the `group by`.  The `textData` might *look* the same, but there are probably differences that might be hard to spot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with sample data and both ways are giving same answer. Have a look. Used aggregations

```
CREATE TABLE PerformanceTable
  (
  TextData VARCHAR(MAX)
 , DatabaseName VARCHAR(100)
 ,CPU BIGINT
 ,READS BIGINT
 ,WRITES BIGINT
, Duration Bigint
 )

 INSERT INTO PerformanceTable  (TextData,DatabaseName,CPU, READS,WRITES,Duration) VALUES ('text', 'master', 45632589,2589633,15106,1457889)
 ,('text', 'master', 45678999,4666767,1001,10002)
 ,('text1', 'DatabSeName', 45678999,6778888,45689,10256)
 ,('text1', 'DatabSeName', 546789,6778888,56378,14578)
 ,('text2', 'MsDb', 546789,6778888,457896,478999)
```

1st way- All other moderators have provided and this should work fine.

```
 SELECT 
  TextData
 ,SUM(CPU) AS cpu_sum
 ,SUM(READS) AS Reads_sum
 ,SUM(WRITES) AS writes_sum
 ,SUM(Duration) AS duration_sum
FROM PerformanceTable
WHERE Duration >1000
GROUP BY TextData
```

Another way

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY TextData ORDER BY TextData ) AS row_id
  ,TextData
  ,SUM(CPU) AS cpu_sum
  ,SUM(READS) AS Reads_sum
  ,SUM(WRITES) AS writes_sum
  ,SUM(Duration) AS duration_sum
FROM PerformanceTable
GROUP BY TextData
) AS A WHERE 
A.row_id = 1
AND  A.duration_sum >1000
```

[image: Result based on added data]